# When to use leading slash in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to understand more clearly the `.gitignore` syntax, and in particular as far as https://github.com/github/gitignore gitignores are concerned.

I see that the leading slash is used to match only pathnames relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file (from http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".

But what happens when i remove the leading slash? As far as what i understood, there are two cases:

1. If the pattern does not contain a slash (or it contains only a trailing slash, which means that it should match a directory), the search is performed inside the entire directory tree. For example, the pattern `dir/` will match `<root>/dir`, `<root>/a/dir`, `<root>/a/b/c/.../dir`, etc., where `<root>` is the location of the `.gitignore` file.
2. If the pattern contains a slash, which is not in the trailing position (it's not the last character), then it is matched only with pathnames relative to the `.gitignore` file location.

These are the examples i made to check this behaviour:

```
# Directory structure:
<root>
├─ dir/
│   └─ test
├─ src/
│   ├─ dir/
│   │   └─ test
test file is there only because Git does not track empty directories.
```

First test:

```
# .gitignore
dir/

# git status
nothing to commit
```

So Git is ignoring both `dir` directories. This is consistent with case number 1: the pattern has no slashes (except for the trailing one), so Git is watching the entire directory tree, ignoring everything that matches the pattern.

Second test:

```
# .gitignore
/dir/

# git status
Untracked files:
    src/
```

Here, Git is ignoring only the `dir` directory directly beneath the root directory, thanks to the leading slash in the pattern.

Third test:

```
# .gitignore
dir/*

# git status
Untracked files:
    src/
```

This is consistent with the case number 2: the pattern has some slash inside it, so it is considered as a pathname starting from the root directory.

Now it's time for the real question. Let's consider [this gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Magento.gitignore): when they ignore the directory `downloader/`, for example, aren't they actually ignoring every single `downloader` directory found in the entire directory tree? This is what i'm driven to think since what i saw about Git's workings before.

So if i happen to have a custom module with a `downloader` directory inside of it, will it be unexpectedly ignored as well as the regular one in the root of Magento? This is a bit of a rethorical question because it actually already happened to me, producing a really hard to find bug.

So, in the Magento `.gitignore` file (which i'm referring to only as an example, btw) a lot of the patterns contain slashes, so they are correctly matched against pathnames starting from the root, but there are a few cases, like `downloader/` or `errors/` that, if i'm not mistaken, are potentially dangerous, and which should probably be changed to `/downloader/` and `/errors/`.

As a more general question, should i always use the leading slash for patterns not containing slashes (except for the trailing one) when i want to select a pathname explicitly starting from root, and not to use it for patterns containing slashes, or should i always use the leading slash for clarity? What do you think about it?

Thank you for reading and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Great question and really nice explanation, I was also bothered with this and your research made things clear to me. After reading this I would say that it is good practice to always start paths with slash if they should start from root, it makes intention more obvious.

Comment: Thanks :) I agree with your note about using slashes to make intentions more explicit.

Comment: This should be part of the .gitignore documentation. Much easier to understand!

Comment: I'd love to see this great post broken up into question and answer sections...

Answer (score 42):

Just wanted to summarize for possible quick future reference -- the leading slash anchors the match to the root. Thus, in the example below, without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within foo because it would take `*` and move recursively down the tree. However, with `/*`, it excludes everything except folder foo and its contents:

```
$ cat .gitignore
/*
!/foo
```

Comment: OK, but incomplete. As I understand it: any *non-trailing* slash (not just the leading) anchors the match to the `.gitignore`'s directory.

Answer (score 35):

You've answered your own question entirely.  If you look at the github/gitignore repo more closely, you'll see most files use inconsistent rules about how patterns are written;  it's very likely most were contributed by people who didn't bother to read the documentation nor test things out as you did.

So if that helps:  You're right, be confident.

If you see mistakes in collaborative projects such as this, don't hesitate to contribute your knowledge.  There's even [some precedent](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/616) if you need to build up your confidence further.

Answer (score 0):

It may have been updated since the question was added, but I think the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) are fairly clear. In particular

> For example, a pattern doc/frotz/ matches doc/frotz directory, but not a/doc/frotz directory; however frotz/ matches frotz and a/frotz that is a directory (all paths are relative from the .gitignore file).

and from the Examples section,

> The pattern doc/frotz and /doc/frotz have the same effect in any .gitignore file. In other words, a leading slash is not relevant if there is already a middle slash in the pattern.