# Should I put nbproject directory under source control in NetBeans

Tags: version-control, netbeans, jakarta-ee

I'm using NetBeans to develop J2EE web service.
NetBeans create a directory called nbproject inside my project directory.
I'm wondering if I should put this directory under source control. I think it is required to build the project without NetBeans.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which NetBeans projects files should go into source control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267403/which-netbeans-projects-files-should-go-into-source-control)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nbProject folder contains all the netbeans metadata about your project. When you go Project -> properties all the settings (and others) that you find there are stored in the nbProjects folder.

EDIT:
This has been answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267580/709399), and the answer there is more complete and accurate

In short you should include `nbproject`, but not `nbproject/private/`.
Add `*/nbproject/private/` to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Guys, correct answer is below. Project's files are something private to developer. Each developer can use it's own editor/IDE/other and their settigns shouldn't be in project.

Answer (score 50):

This is usually not required. Think of it this way: If I was to check out your project but happened to be using a different IDE, I would not require your `nbproject` directory. In other words: This directory is machine specific, not project specific. Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, seriously. nbproject, like Eclipse project files should not be versioned. They are machine specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building your project with Maven or Gradle you should definitely exclude the folder from the VCS.