# Clone an Eclipse project repository into Netbeans from GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github, netbeans, repository, clone

I am pretty new to GitHub.

This is my problem: We (4 people) are working on a Java project. Two of us are using **NetBeans** and two of us are using **Eclipse**. Let`s say 1 person created a project from Eclipse and pushed the project into the repository. Now, I want to clone the repository and work on the project. I can successfully clone the project and I can see all the files that we have in the repository. However, ***I cannot run*** the project. In fact, when I am cloning the project, NetBeans asks me for creating a new project. I do not want to create a new project but I want to work on the same project that I am able to run it.

What is solution?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to commit the **Eclipse** project meta-files (`.project`,  `.classpath` and may be the `.settings` directory) **and** the **NetBeans** project meta-files (I don't know the corresponding meta-file names for NetBeans).

From your problem description it seems the NetBeans project meta-files are missing in the github repository. Hence, NetBeans doesn't recognize the cloned repository as a project.

See also: [Which NetBeans projects files should go into source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267403/which-netbeans-projects-files-should-go-into-source-control).